# Windows Workflow rules engine - determine which rule is executing

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity, rule-engine

***SETUP***

We are using the Windows Workflow Rules Engine to implement a discounting system. Our rule setup is as follows:

```
Rule Name: 10% Discount on Foo Chairs
Priority: 0
Reevaluation: Never
Active: True
Condition: this.MatchesSKUs("SKU1", "SKU2")
Then Actions: this.ForMatchingSkus.ApplyDiscount(.10m)
```

We have several such rules defined and some products may fall under more than one rule. Within our "cart" object we have a method that executes the rule engine.

```
var discountEngine = new DiscountEngine(discountRuleSetEnabled);
var execution = new RuleExecution(validation, discountEngine);
discountEngine.ruleExecution = execution;
if (discountRuleSet.RuleSet != null)
{ discountRuleSet.RuleSet.Execute(execution); }
```

Discounts are working all well and good and everything is **almost** fine.

***ISSUE***

As the rules are executing I need to keep track of rules that are actually used and provide a discount > 0. For instance the rule above ultimately runs the

```
ApplyDiscount(decimal discountPercent)
```

method, which tacks on a discount object to the cart line item. I need to know that this instance of "Apply Discount" was called via the **10% Discount on Foo Chairs** rule. I've tried various methods but can't find where the context of each rule is passed along. I've been looking at the **ActivityExecutionContext** object but I'm having trouble getting the context within the condition or action methods that I have setup.

Comment: I know nothing about WF but have experience with several other rules engines. Just out of curiosity: what do you do if the business decides to change a condition, or priority, or action of any of your rule? Re-test, re-compile, re-deploy?

Comment: We have a test set we can run through before we publish any rule changes to the live environment.

Comment: But you do have to recompile the project, right?

Comment: No, the rules are serialized into an XML string and stored in the database. The Workflow Foundation has a control that allows you to design the rules and we just save them to the database.